# Double Consonants on String

Tags: javascript

I'm introducing Javascript and I need help at this exercice:

Write a `function translate()` that will return a **transformed** and **doubled  lowercase string**  in a special way : 
double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between them.
For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".

At the moment I have this:

```
function translate(str){
  var result=""; 
  return result;
}
var t="this is fun";
console.log( translate(t) );
var t="aaee";
console.log( translate(t) );
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: In other words you have nothing yet.

Comment: I don't know how to split strings and add double consonants and add "o" between them

Comment: So what else do you have to work off from your chapter you are on? So either you have worked with loops or regular expressions.

Comment: I never worked with loops at JavaScript, only with regular expressions like I have three numbers and I need to check what is higher.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
var consonants = [
    'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j',
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r',
    's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z'
];

var translate = function(str) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (cosonants.indexOf(str[i]) === -1) {
            result += str[i];
            continue;
        }
        result += str[i] + 'o' + str[i];
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

- go through the str letter by letter (iterate through chars of string)
- add (append: `+=` or `+` operator) the letter to result string
- check if letter is not a vocal by comparing agains a, e, i, o, u *(use boolean operators for equality `===` `!===`, and boolean logical operators and `&&`, or `||`. or use array with `indexOf()` method)*
- if it is add (append) "o" and letter again

---

- look up how to do these steps

Comment: Thanks for those steps, really going to help me understanding this exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, which is looking for consonats and replace it with the found consonant, o and the consonant.

```js
console.log("this is fun".replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/g, '$&o$&'));
```